# Easist way to pass strings in a console app

Tags: c#

I really wanted to just use

```
Class MyClasses
{

    public string mwaAHA = "here";
    //and then use it like this:

    static void testStringhere()
    {

        console.writeline(mwaAHA);

    }
}
```

I'm doing something wrong can someone demo the eaist way I can make a few strings and use them in any void?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `testStringhere()` is static, it only has access to other static members residing in the same scope.

To solve your issue in this case use

```
public static string mwaAHA = "here";
```

Comment: I get Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is right, but it should probably also have a private and a const..something like:

```
private const string str = "here";
```